# Plot image over a bar in barplot in r

Tags: r, graph

I want to create a barplot in R where over each bar there is a figure.

Is there a way in which i can accomplish this? I have made an (horrible) example

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `plot` and `png`

```
 library(png)
 library(grid)
 library(ggplot2)

 img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
 g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

 qplot(x=sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE), geom="blank") +
     annotation_custom(g, xmin=4.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=3, ymax=4) +
     geom_bar()
```

and also a slightly extended version which shows
   - the same example using plot
   - calculates the location of the image for a specific location

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

p<- ggplot(data.frame(x=x), aes(x=x)) +
  geom_bar()

stats <- p$layers[[1]]$stat$compute_group(p$data)

loc=5
val=max(c(stats[stats$x==loc,]$count,0))
p+annotation_custom(g, xmin=loc-0.5, xmax=loc+0.5, ymin=val, ymax=val+1)+ylim(0,6)
```

[image]

Comment: qplot from which package?

Comment: I also added how to extract the location from the plot for a specific bar